Flask-Socketio not emitting in worker thread
I have a program with a queue and a worker thread that executes everything in the queue. When the thread is done processing a job, it should emit some data. It says it is emitting, but the client side doesn't receive the message. When I emit something using the exact some command in the test endpoint, it does work.
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session 
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, engineio_logger=True, logger=True, cors_allowed_origins="*")
job_queue = Queue()

def worker():
    while True:
        sid, job = job_queue.get()
        if job is None:
            break

        print(f"Processing {job}", flush=True)
        time.sleep(2)
        
        
        socketio.emit("response", {"filename": job}, to=sid)
        print(f"Emitted response to {sid}", flush=True)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('test.html')

@app.route("/test", methods=["POST"])
def test():
    sid = request.args.get('sid')
    job_queue.put((sid, "test"))
    socketio.emit("response", {"filename": "test"}, to=sid)
    return "OK", 200

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/')
def connected():
    print("Connected", flush=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=worker, daemon=True).start()
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)

I have added the sid as a parameter to the emit, because clients are given a room with their sid name. Like this I can get past the 'socketio emitting out of scope' error.
I have also tried to use socketio.start_background_task(), but this did'nt work either.

What kind of concurrency are you using in this application? If you are using greenlets (gevent or eventlet) then this is wrong, you cannot use Socket.IO on a different threads. In this case you have to run all your background tasks as greenlets for them to be compatible.
